# What happens if the holder of a lock tries to acquire a lock?

Tags: concurrency, mutual-exclusion, deadlocks

In a system, suppose there is a process and a resource with only one instance.

Let us assume that the process holds the instance and requests the same instance of that resource. Will there be a deadlock? Under what circumstances?

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried for the second question and where did you get stuck? What is the locking mechanism you assume?

Answer (score 4):

Resources that can only be used by a single process at a time are usually protected by a lock. If the process that currently holds the lock attempts to acquire it a second time, what happens depends on the type of lock.

- If the lock is [reentrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex), then it can be acquired multiple times by the same process. The process will need to call the release function as many times as it called the acquire function.
- If the lock is not reentrant (for example if it's a simple semaphore or an atomically-modified boolean), then a second attempt will block. You can call this a single-process deadlock.
- In some mutex implementations (probably not in what is studied in Concurrency 101 though), a process can acquire the same lock more than once, and the second time is a no-op, so the process must only call the release function once. Another thing that sometimes happens is that calling the acquire function from the same process twice puts the implementation in a bad state after which anything can happen — the semantics doesn't define what happens in that case.

Thus, it depends on what semantics your locks have. You can build non-reentrant locks on top of reentrant locks or vice versa if all you have is the wrong kind for what you want to do.